# proving not (iff a (not a)) with basic tactics

Tags: logic, coq

My experience proving contradictory things in Coq is very limited and I can't find an explicit way to prove the following theorem with basic tactics:

`Theorem thrm : forall a, not (iff a (not a)).`

I can prove it immediately with `firstorder` or `intuition`, but these tactics are like magic to me, my impression is that they involve some sophisticated automation. What would be a more explicit way to prove this theorem with simple explicit tactics such as `rewrite`, `destruct`, `apply`, `assert`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to prove a negated proposition `not something`, one can use the `intros` tactic to add the expectedly-wrong assumption to the context and then prove that the context indeed is inconsistent. This is due to the fact `not something` is an abbreviation for `something -> False`. You can notice this by typing `Print not.` or during a proof, `unfold not.` to substitute the goal accordingly.

Then, to discharge the goal so obtained, several tactics may be used depending on the context, for example:

- tactics `intros`, `apply`, `exact` and `assumption` for minimal propositional logic;
- tactics such as `destruct`, `inversion`, `discriminate` or `injection` in the presence of inductive types;
- etc., see the [Coq reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html)

In your example, `intros`, `destruct`, `apply` and `assumption` are enough:

```
Theorem thrm : forall a, not (iff a (not a)).
Proof.
intros a Hiff; destruct Hiff as [H1 H2].
apply H1; apply H2; intros Ha; apply H1; assumption.
Qed.
```

Note that the proof can also be shortened to this equivalent version:

```
Theorem thrm : forall a, not (iff a (not a)).
Proof. now intros a [H1 H2]; apply H1; apply H2; intros Ha; apply H1. Qed.
```

where `now something` is a notation for `something; easy` (cf. the [doc](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.7.1/refman/tactics.html#hevea_tactic166)).

Hoping this helps